# Flutter: SharedPreferences not synched in different functions

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I am new to Flutter / mobile development and using package shared_preferences in my app together with android_alarm_manager_plus. My problem is that different functions report different states of shared preferences and thus cannot cooperate as intended.

The app lets users fulfill certain tasks with task-specific frequencies (daily, weekly, ...). Users may choose a time of the day (e.g., 11 am) when they want to be reminded of current tasks. An `AndroidAlarmManager.periodic` with duration of 24 hours is set to that time of the day and calls a `schedule()` function. The `schedule()` function checks if it is time to schedule again and which of the tasks are due, then adds those of a list of due tasks which is used as a base for the task widget to serve those. When a task is fulfilled, it removes itself from this list.

There are several values in shared preferences being used for this:

- `dateOfLastScheduling`: the last day scheduling has been performed (used to prevent from scheduling multiple times per day)
- `last_time_<Task>` for each task the app knows: the last day the task has been fulfilled
- `scheduledTasks`: list of current tasks to fulfill

My shared preferences are one variable in a file named `storage.dart` (handling persistence in general) which is initialized in the App's first/landing page's `initState()` like:

```
SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((loadedPrefs) async {
      storage.sharedPrefs = loadedPrefs;
      ...
```

Whenever I read or write those preferences in any of my files, I use storage.sharedPrefs. I do this because I read here that having shared preferences as a "singleton" like this is preferable over loading them locally everywhere - which I did before, with the same problems.

Now, for testing purposes, I introduced a button on another Route that just prints out my current prefs after converting them to a Map, and another that actually sets values, such as `dateOfLastScheduling`, so I can test scheduling.

Test-printing shared preferences with this button regularly yields different results than printing them in the `schedule()` function. Additionally, when I change, e.g., the date of last scheduling here, the function will not have these changes, instead work with an older version of shared preferences, and thus not schedule. When it does schedule, the tasks are added to `scheduledTasks`, believing a local print, but these changes, in turn, are not reflected anywhere else and the Widget serving tasks also does not know of it. Sometimes, hitting the print button several times eventually leads to an update.

It seems like every function is using their own (cached?) version of shared preferences, which is sort of the opposite of shared. Even doing `storage.sharedPrefs.reload()` does not really seem to change anything.

Am I missing something obvious here? How do I have to use shared preferences, so that they are the same everywhere and updated immediately?

Comment: Could the AndroidAlarmManager.periodic's running in a seperate Isolate be part of the problem? Are shared prefs shared between Isolates?